# What is the easiest way to find and replace text in 20 text files in a directory?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

I have 20 text files with various extensions in a directory.

I want to replace "**nnn**" with "**ooo**" in all files.

I could import them into a project in `Eclipse` or `Visual Studio` to replace them all but that is overkill and would add other meta files etc.

What is a **simple** way to do this, I'm thinking: select all files, right click, choose some tool called (e.g. "QuickReplacer") and fill in find and replace, click and done.

Does anyone know of a tool like this?

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you're already using Eclipse, bringing up the Find in Files (or whatever it's called) you can choose a Directory, rather than an existing project, to search. It shouldn't be hard from there to then run a find/replace on matched files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GrepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin) would do this among others, and it is a Explorer plugin.

However there is quite a big array of different applications available that can do this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018427/suggestions-for-a-command-line-search-and-replace-tool-on-windows) SO thread on the topic also suggest [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) as an option.

Comment: installed it and did my search/replace within 3 minutes, thanks!

Answer (score 36):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) can do it easily...

`Search` menu → `Find in Files...` menu item.

---

In Notepad++ 7.9.2

Go to

`File` → `Open Containing Folder` → `Folder as Workspcae`

Right click on your folder and select `Find in Files...`

In `Find in Files` dialog, click on tab `Find in Files` and fill your keyword in `Find what` then fill the replacement in `Replace with` and click on <kbd>Find All</kbd> button to find all occurrences keyword in all files, or <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd> button, to replace all occurrences of keyword with its replacement.

Comment: This is great solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you are familiar with Visual Studio, you can do that without creating a project. Do (something like): `Edit>Find/Replace>Find in Files`. There you can specify a *folder*.

I've done this many times. I'd say it's only overkill if you had to create a project (you don't) or if you didn't have VS installed and needed it only for this request.

Answer (score 3):

[Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Replaces text in all open files, or you can specify particular folder(s) by clicking `…`.

Afterwards, hit `File` > `Save All`.

Answer (score 2):

I find that [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com) is very useful for this kind of thing, amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the [WildEdit](http://www.textpad.com/products/wildedit/index.html) product by Helios Software (makers of the excellent Textpad text editor).

It's reliable, quick, flexible, and doesn't cost much (£8.50 = approx. 10 Euro) - well worth its price!

It handles ASCII, ANSI, UTF-8 and other encoding with no problem, you can pick a directory and a file mask (*.cs, *.as?x etc.) and apply the changes only to those files, and it will keep a backup of your original files in case you want to undo the change.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) has this built in on Windows - so long as all the files are in the same directory (and is a very small and quick general purpose text editor into the bargain) - right click and 'Edit with SciTE' any one file in the directory, Ctrl+Shift+F, type in search and replace strings and an optional filename filter and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the Party, Just wanted to Mention this great free tool.
http://dngrep.github.io/

Comment: Thank you! This is a very useful tool, it will help me to save a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Try Text Replacer, take a look at this page : https://textreplacer.g-software.ma

[Text Replacer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa0l1.png)

[Text Replacer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XbDr.png)